# What does split function look like?

Tags: javascript, split

I came across this statement :

```
userName = document.cookie.split("=")[1];
```

after reading about split statement [here at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp). which says that syntax of split is
`string.split(separator, limit)`. Then what does the square bracket after first parens. mean ?
If this is true what does `split` function look like ?

Comment: http://w3fools.com - Get a decent Javascript book instead.

Answer (score 5):

`String.split(separator, limit)` returns an array. In Javascript, you can access array values by index using the square brackets. Arrays are zero-based, `0` is the first element, `1` the second and so on.

The equivalent of your code would be:

```
var arr = document.cookie.split("=");
userName = arr[1];
```

This separates the `document.cookie` by the equal-sign (`=`) and takes the second element (index 1) from it. `document.cookie` is a special property (datatype: String)  of the `document` object which contains all cookies of a webpage, separated by the `;` character. E.g. if document.cookie contains `name=Adam`, the array `arr` will contain the values `name` and `Adam`. The second one is stored in `userName`.

Note that if the cookie contains multiple values, or if the value contains multiple equal-signs, it won't work. Consider the next cases:

- `document.cookie` contains `name=Adam; home=Nowhere`. Using the above code, this would make `userName` contain `Adam; home` because the string is separated by the equal-sign, and then the second value is taken.
- `document.cookie` contains `home=Nowhere; name=Adam`. This would result in `userName` containing `Nowhere; name`
- `document.cookie` contains `name=Adam=cool`. In this case, `userName` would be `Adam` and not `Adam=cool`.

Also, w3schools is [not that reliable](http://w3fools.com). Use more authorative sources like the Mozilla Developer Network:

- [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.cookie)
- [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: and what does `document.cookie` actually mean ? What does it return ?

Comment: `document.cookie` contains the cookies of a page. It acts special, when you retrieve the value from it, all cookies are returned, separated by `;`. If you set it to `name=Adam; max-age=60`, it'll set the `name=Adam` cookie with a lifetime of 60 seconds.

Comment: when i write `document.cookie != ""` how does browser know, **that** particular page had stored cookie once ?

Comment: If there are no cookies stored, `document.cookie` evaluates to an empty string. Example code: `if (document.cookie != "") { alert("There are no cookies"); }`. The browser takes care of storing cookies, which may expire after a while (set using the `max-age` or `expires` field of a cookie). See also the linked documentation

Answer (score 2):

The `split` function returns an `array` of strings split by the given separator. With the square bracket you are accessing the nth element of that (returned) array.

If you are familiar with Java, its the same behavior as the String.split() method there.

Answer (score 1):

It gets the second index of the resulting array

Same as:

```
var split = document.cookie.split("=");
var userName = split[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

split returns an array of strings. So square brackets mean get second string from the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

The square bracket in the code you supplied is accessing the second element of the array returned by `split()`.  The function itself returns an array.  That code would be the same as:

```
var temp = document.cookie.split("=");
userName = temp[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Split would return an array e.g. [1, 2, 3]. If you supply the square bracket after it, it will return the specified key in the brackets, in this case userName would be 2

Answer (score 1):

You [shouldn't be using w3schools](http://w3fools.com/), but...

In JavaScript, function parameters are optional and it is possible to supply fewer parameters than the function expects. The extra parameters in the function are then undefined. Some functions are programmed to deal with that possibility and `string.split` is one of them.

The other part has to do with the fact that `split` returns an array. Arrays can then be indexed using the square bracket notation, hence the `[1]` after the function call.